# Refering a model in sub-directory in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm writing a Rails Application.

My model tree looks something like this:

```
models/
|-  user.rb
|-  ...
|-  forum/
  |- thread.rb
  |- forum.rb
```

A user has many threads.

When I try this:

```
has_many :forum_threads
```

I get the following error when trying to refer it:

```
uninitialized constant User::ForumThread
```

However, when I try this:

```
has_many :threads
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `scoped' for Thread:Class
```

What have I done wrong?
What can be causing this?

Comment: Thread is a reserved work in rails (http://latheesh.com/2010/02/02/rails-reserved-words/).

Comment: Have you added a namespace to the models under the forum directory? as in `Forum::Thread`.

Comment: @spullen Yes, I have. This code was generated using `rails generate`.

Comment: @spullen Also, this repeats for other models in the forum directory ('comments' etc.)

Comment: maybe you just need to set the class name `has_many :forum_threads, :class_name => 'Forum::Thread'`

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it. I only had to add a :class_name specifier to the `has_many` decleration:

```
has_many :forum_threads, class_name: 'Forum::Thread'
```